# CSS variables and custom properties - How do they work?

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

**dynamic-text-colors.css**

```
:root {
   --title-color: #555555;
}

.text-title-color {
    color: var(--title-color);
}

.bg-blue-100 {
   --title-color: #999999;
}

.bg-blue-200 {
   --title-color: #888888;
}

.bg-blue-300 {
   --title-color: #777777;
}
```

**index.html**

```
 <div class="bg-blue-100">
      <h1 class="text-title-color">I am colored #999999</h1> 
 </div>
      
 <div class="bg-blue-200">
      <h1 class="text-title-color">I am colored #888888</h1> 
 </div>

 <div class="bg-blue-300">
      <h1 class="text-title-color">I am colored #777777</h1> 
 </div>
```

**Question**:

I don't understand the process that allows each h1 to have a different color. In this instance, I don't understand how the value of "text-title-color" can be different based the background color.

> "Custom properties are scoped to the element(s) they are declared on, and participate in the cascade: the value of such a custom property is that from the declaration decided by the cascading algorithm." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

According to the explanation above of custom props by Mozilla, each variable is scoped to its element its decalred on. As such, would the browser some how convert the code to something like this and if so where is the code below stored?:

```
.bg-blue-100 .text-title-color{
      color: #999999
}

.bg-blue-200 .text-title-color{
      color: #888888
}

.bg-blue-300 .text-title-color{
      color: #777777
}
```

Comment: `color: --title-color;` has to be `color: var(--title-color);`

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't need to do any conversion in the way you describe

The variables are all part of what it understands.

It's not like a preprocessor which has to convert everything to 'real' CSS before anything runs.

When the browser has to render an h1, say, as in your question it will pick up the value for --title-color from whichever style is relevant. Just as it would pick up, say, the color or width if they were set there.

The value of CSS variables is precisely because they can be set at run time, e.g. by Javascript on some user action and the new value will be used 'on the fly'.